# Using sed to swap columns X and X+1 inline in delimited file

Tags: sed

I have a file with multiple lines and for line 2 to the end of the file I want to swap fields 8 and 9. The file is comma separated and I'd like to do the swap inline so I can run it on a batch of files using `*` wildcard. If this can be accomplished similarly with `awk` then that works for me too.

example:

```
header1,header2,header3,...,header8,header9,...,headerN
field1.1,...,field1.9,field1.8,...,field1.N
field2.1,...,field2.9,field2.8,...,field2.N
field3.1,...,field3.9,field3.8,...,field3.N
...
```

I think the command would look similar to `sed -r -i '2,$s/^(([^,]*,){8})([^,]*,)([^,]*,)(.*)/\1\3\2\4/' temp*.log`,
but `\2` is not what I expect, it is the 7th field. I know that `\2` will not be the 8th field because I have double parentheses there, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Could somebody please explain what this equation is doing and specifically what `[^,]` is doing and how the `{8}` is applied?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `awk`, you might use:

```
awk -F',' 'BEGIN {OFS=","} {t = $8; $8 = $9; $9 = t; print}'
```

In `sed`, the command is more convoluted, but it could be done.

```
sed -e 's/^\(\([^,]*,\)\{7\}\)\([^,]*,\)\([^,]*,\)/\1\4\3/'
```

Add the `-i .bak` option if your version of `sed` (e.g. GNU or BSD) supports it.

This uses the universally available `sed` regexes (it would work on even archaic versions of `sed`). You could lose most of the backslashes if you used 'extended regular expressions' instead:

```
sed -r -i 's/^(([^,]*,){7})([^,]*,)([^,]*,)/\1\4\3\5/'
```

Note the nested remembered (captured) patterns.  The outer set is `\1`, the inner set would be `\2` but that gets repeated 7 times, so you'd have the seventh field as `\2`.  Anyway, that's why the eighth and ninth columns are switched with `\4` and `\3`. `\5` are the remaining columns.

(I note in passing that it would have been helpful to have some sample data in sufficiently the correct format to test with.  It was a nuisance having to edit what is shown in the question to be able to test the code.)

If you need to do much CSV work, then either use Perl and its CSV modules ([Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3A%3ACSV) and [Text::CSV_XS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3A%3ACSV_XS)) or Python and its CSV module, or get [CSVfix](http://code.google.com/p/csvfix/).

Comment: I'd like to use `sed -i` to support wildcards in filename. Can this be done with `awk` 3.1.5?

Answer (score 1):

#### $2 is the second part in the RE

Denumbered by first occurence of `(`.

So in

```
'2,$s/^(([^,]*,){8})([^,]*,)([^,]*,)(.*)/\1\3\2\4/'
```

You could see (followind alignment):

```
 $1 =  (([^,]*,){8})
 $2 =   ([^,]*,)
 $3 =               ([^,]*,)
 $4 =                       ([^,]*,)
 and finaly $5 =                    (.*)
```

In this specific case, `$2` must hold the *last match* of the height (`{8}`).

Comment: What does `[^,]` even mean?

Comment: @Stuart: `[^,]` is a negated character class; it matches anything except a comma.  Hence `[^,]*` is zero of more non-commas; `[^,]*,` is zero or more non-commas followed by a comma.  I used the same in my `sed` script.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that awk is the right tool:

```
awk -F',' -v OFS=',' '{t=$8;$8=$9;$9=t}7' file
```

Comment: I'd like to use `sed -i` to support wildcards in filename. Can this be done with `awk` 3.1.5?

Comment: @Stuart you could wrap the awk line with a little `for` loop to make it work on multiple files. To write change back, you could : `awk '...' file > tmp.file && mv tmp.file file`

Comment: @Stuart To answer your question, no it cannot be done with `awk v3.1.5`. However, in-place changes can be done with `GNU awk 4.1` or later. Read [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Extension-Sample-Inplace) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -ri '1!s/(,[^,]*)(,[^,]*)/\2\1/4' file
```

This swaps the 9th field with the 8th i.e. 8 / 2 = 4, if you wanted the 7th with the 8th:

```
sed -ri '1!{s/^/,/;s/(,[^,]*)(,[^,]*)/\2\1/4;s/^,//}' file
```

Comment: You are going to have to explain this one `sed -ri '1!s/(,[^,]*)(,[^,]*)/\2\1/4' file`. It looks completely wrong to me.

Comment: @Stuart this swaps the 4th occurance of two fields i.e. 9th for 8th.

Comment: Can you explain how it works? How does it choose 7th and 8th?